# Как сделать авторизацию в google через android?

Tags: android, kotlin

https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Сделал всё как по ссылке сверху. В методе handleSignInResult покывает что я не зашел в аккаунт. Хотя на телефоне подтверждение, что зашел появляется, что не так??

```
fun handleSignInResult(result:GoogleSignInResult ){
    Log.i("Google", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess) {
        val acct:GoogleSignInAccount = result.signInAccount!!

        Log.i("Google", "Name: " + acct.displayName + ", familyName: " + acct.familyName
                + ", Image: " + acct.photoUrl.toString());

    } else {//Не вошел
        Log.i("Google", "не зашел")
        error("Google не зашел")
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте ещё `result.getStatusCode()` что возвращает

Comment: Думаю я догадался в чем проблема входа: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null} А ещё не подскажите где взять имя, фамилию и картинку входящего пользователя?